# Why doesn't com.sun.media.sound package documented in Java SE 6 apidoc?

Tags: java, package, media, javadoc, java-6

I see that I have `com.sun.media.sound` package withing `rt.jar` file of my `jdk1.6.0_25` distribution. But I see no javadocs for it in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

What is the role of this package? What is it part of? I can find some javadocs for it with Google (like here http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/media/sound/package-index.html), but how to know which is correct for SE 6? Why doesn't it docummented in main javadoc?

**EDIT**

So, I understand that they are not of public API, but what they are used for? Why do they documented in openjdk javadoc? Are they public there?

Comment: Because it's not part of the "official" java spec, it's a Sun (or nowadays, Oracle)-specific API that you shouldn't rely on if you intend to be compatible with any other Java impl. than Oracles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These classes are proprietary and internal, they are not intended for public use. They are also a subject to change in the future. Close your eyes, don't look at them and never use them.

Comment: Sadly, sometimes its convenient to use them to avoid importing 3rd party packages.  This particular package is a problem for OpenJDK which has to snap up these packages from another distribution due to licensing restrictions.  Wouldn't it be great if everyone could play nice?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, `com.sun.*` classes are not part of Public API of JDK and are implementation details subject to change without prior notice.